# laravel auth не работает с другой схемой из базы данных postgre

Tags: laravel, postgresql, auth

При развертывании проекта (в составе которого есть приложение laravel) создается БД PostgreSQL и схема site, а так же (среди прочих таблиц) таблица users в схеме site. Таблицы создаются скриптом через psql. Так же в site.users скриптом добавляется запись с логином admin и Bcrypt паролем. Bcrypt пароль сгенерирован с помощью `Hash::make("password");` laravel'овским (на любой странице сделал echo и скопировал полученное для скрипта), то есть, условно, получается в скрипте следующая строка:

```
INSERT INTO site.users (login, password) VALUES ('admin', '$2a$12$q9/9Nb2QABtNCrEcRvVFvuErYMxP5.Y3zcMGIH.QefbOA4WCyeAfO');
```

В .env файл laravel'а указаны все параметры для БД, всё работает.

Я выполнил `php artisan ui:auth`, но миграции я не использую, мне нужен только интерфейс login. Все лишние файлы вообще удалены (все миграции, контроллеры по регистрации, восстановлению и т.д.)

В модели User переопределил:

```
protected $table = "site.users";
protected $fillable = [
    ...
    'login',
    ...
];
```

В LoginController переопределил:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'login';
}
```

И, соответственно, подправил login.blade.php файл:

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="login" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Логин') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="login" type="login" class="form-control @error('login') is-invalid @enderror" name="login" value="{{ old('login') }}" required autocomplete="login" autofocus>
    
        @error('login')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

На странице логина ввожу созданные скриптом логин и пароль, но мне всегда выдает

> These credentials do not match our records.

В чем может быть проблема?

**Updated**

Вывод `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` из метода login трейта AuthenticatesUsers

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть даже, якобы, записи нет с таким логином, хотя она есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я проверял стандартный ui:auth с миграцией, после регистрации логин работает...

Answer (score 0):

Будьте внимательны, дамы и господа...

В общем, я еще добавил дополнительный коннект в config/database.php, изменил search_path (она же - схема):

```
'pgsql_site' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'search_path' => 'site',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],
```

Ну и в модель User указал:

```
protected $connection = 'pgsql_site';
```

А проблема была в этой строчке:

```
<input id="login" type="login" class="form-control @error('login') is-invalid @enderror" name="login" value="{{ old('login') }}" required autocomplete="login" autofocus>
```

type="login"........

Прошу прощения за глупость. Вопрос закрыт.